# Export my products for Facebook products feed

Tags: products, export, facebook

Is there a way to export my products from a certain category to create a CSV file to import into our Facebook page products?

Results need to look like this [image]

Comment: Which version are you using? You can use magento dataflow profile for export product. You can make filed label and map to attribute and you can also filter products for export. Another way is you can use custom module

Comment: knowing the results need to look like this [link](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0070/7032/files/product_catalog_example_facebook.png)

how do we achieve that?

Comment: You can use some custom module or code like [this](http://www.vuleticd.com/2013/01/27/export-product-ids-with-magento-dataflow-advanced-profiles/) in default magento will not export product id and category name. it will export category ids.

Comment: I am using 1.9.2. I tried the dataflow profile and created it. I ran it but it took forever and never got the results. Our site has about 40,000 products.